# Electric potential surrounding an offset point charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential

I am self learning electromagnetic fields by going through the homework assignments found [here](https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/ece303/Homeworks/Homeworks.htm). I am stuck on the first question of the second assignment...

[image]

Their solution says that this is equivalent to solving for a dipole separated by a distance $d$. The solution being...
$$\Phi(\vec r) = \frac{qdcos(\theta)}{4\pi\epsilon_o r^2},\,z>0$$

While I understand why this works, I would like to solve without the dipole setup. Could someone please help me with the solution?

EDIT:

I have decided to just attempt to better understand the dipole solution; I do not understand why we can make this step:

$$\Phi(\vec r)=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_o}\left(\frac{dcos(\theta)}{r^2-\frac{d^2}{4}cos^2(\theta)}\right)\Longrightarrow\Phi(\vec r) = \frac{qdcos(\theta)}{4\pi\epsilon_o r^2}$$

Why does $\frac{d^2}{4}cos^2(\theta)=0$ when $z>0$?

Comment: Well, the method of images *greatly* simplifies such problems. Do you have a reason for not wanting to use it? As I see it, if you don't want to use this method, you would need to know the formula for the charge induced on the plate, and then use this (non-uniform!) charge density to calculate the field. I don't see it as being very doable...

Comment: @Philip Okay, that's fair. My only reason for not wanting to use it was because the solution was hard to follow; they arrived at the answer in 2 lines. Could you show me, in more detail, how to work out the solution when applying the method of images?

Comment: That's the strength of the argument: once you've learnt it, a particular set of otherwise difficult problems suddenly becomes quite easy to solve. I believe every decent book on the subject would have a chapter on it. For example, Chapter 3.2 in Griffiths' *Electrodynamics* is a fantastic resource. There are also many questions about this on Phys.SE.

Comment: @Philip I checked Griffiths but the solution was for rectangular coordinates and I couldn't find my question on PSE. Could you please see my update?

Answer (score 0):

The surface charge density must be such that E is perpendicular to the surface, that is, it must cancel the parallel component of the field of the point charge. Use Gauss's law for that.

Comment: So you're suggesting to use Gauss's law to find the electric field first and then solve for potential from that? I tried that but had a hard time simplifying the solution for the electric field.

Comment: You know the point charge field at the metal surface. You need to find the surface charge distribution such that its divergence cancels the parallel components.

Answer (score 0):

There are, as I see it, two different problems here:

1. How does the method of images allow us to relate the stated problem of a point charge and infinite plate to the (simpler) problem of a dipole? The answer to this (as I have explained in a comment above) can be seen in any textbook on electrodynamics (I would suggest Chapter 3.2 of Griffiths' *Electrodynamics*).
2. Once this has been understood, it can be shown that in the region $z>0$, $$\Phi(r) = \frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\left(\frac{d\cos{\theta}}{r^2 - \frac{d^2}{4}\cos^2{\theta} }\right),$$ which reduces to $$\Phi(r) = \frac{q d \cos{\theta}}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2}.$$ This is an *approximation*, it is not generally true. However, there is something in the question that *allows* you to make this approximation. I will not give you the answer (it's really quite simple) because this is very much a "homework-style" question, but check to see if there are any assumptions in the problem that you have not used yet (or which might sound superfluous, but aren't).